# Common numbers in two arrays without redundancy?

Tags: arrays, pascal

I am stuck in this problem ~ so it's basically to fill two arrays with same size n (T1 and T2 for example ) with random integers between 0 and 9 and then search for common numbers between the two arrays and save them in another array (T3) without redundancy ,means for example if T1 have 4,5,0,6,4,2 and T2 have 0,9,1,5,7,4 T3 will be 4,5,0 only without having to repeat 4 twice ~ I've done most of the thing but still stuck in how to save once if the number exists more than one time in the array ~ I'm using pascal btw but if you don't know its syntax ,it's alright,just tell me in english how to resolve this PROBLEM ! ! !!

Comment: You should put a code sample and if possible a paste of stdout. You're lucky to get such a high quality response.

Comment: Tags here have a specific meaning, and you should read the description of the tag before you use it. Your question has nothing to do with redundancy as that tag is defined, so I removed it. Adding proper tags (and not adding them at random because they have familiar names or words) helps get your question to users who can answer it more quickly, and aids in searches by future readers who are also trying to find an answer to their problems. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Since the range is limited to `0..9`, you can simply use some extra arrays to indicate which source array the number was found in. Examine the following pseudo-code and description:

```
array T1 = (4,5,0,6,4,2);
array T2 = (0,9,1,5,7,4);

array foundInT1 = (false, 10 times)
array foundInT2 = (false, 10 times)
for each element in T1:
    foundInT1[element] = true
for each element in T2:
    foundInT2[element] = true

array T3 = ()
for each element in 0..9 inclusive:
    if foundInT1[element] and foundInT2[element]:
        T3.append(element)
```

So, the basic idea is to have two ten-element arrays, one for each of the source lists. They're all initialised to false before-hand.

Then, for every element in `T1`, set the corresponding entry to true in the `foundInT1` array. Setting it to true will simply ignore the fact that there may be duplicates as a duplicate will simply set it to true again (effectively making no change).

Ditto for the `T2` and `foundInT2` arrays. Then you have two arrays containing information that can be correlated using the index.

Once that's done, simply cycle through all the possible numbers `0..9` and, provided they were found both in `T1` and `T2`, add them to (the initially empty) `T3`.

In more detail:

```
input  foundInT1   foundInT2
       0123456789  0123456789
=====  ==========  ==========
       ..........  ..........
 t1=4  ....t.....  ..........
 t1=5  ....tt....  ..........
 t1=0  t...tt....  ..........
 t1=6  t...ttt...  ..........
 t1=4  t...ttt...  ..........
 t1=2  t.t.ttt...  ..........

 t2=0  t.t.ttt...  t.........
 t2=9  t.t.ttt...  t........t
 t2=1  t.t.ttt...  tt.......t
 t2=5  t.t.ttt...  tt...t...t
 t2=7  t.t.ttt...  tt...t.t.t
 t2=4  t.t.ttt...  tt..tt.t.t
```

Then, when you put together the two `foundInTx` arrays:

```
  0123456789
  ==========
  t.t.ttt...
& tt..tt.t.t
  ==========
  t...tt....
```

you can see that the only values in *both* arrays are for `(0,4,5)`.

The following Python code shows a proof-of-concept:

```
t1 = [4,5,0,6,4,2]
t2 = [0,9,1,5,7,4]

inT1 = [False] * 10
inT2 = [False] * 10

for elem in t1: inT1[elem] = True
for elem in t2: inT2[elem] = True

t3 = []
for elem in range(10):
    if inT1[elem] and inT2[elem]:
        t3.append(elem)

print "t1   =", t1
print "t2   =", t2
print "inT1 =", inT1
print "inT2 =", inT2
print "t3   =", t3
```

When running that, the output is:

```
t1   = [4, 5, 0, 6, 4, 2]
t2   = [0, 9, 1, 5, 7, 4]
inT1 = [True, False, True, False, True, True, True, False, False, False]
inT2 = [True, True, False, False, True, True, False, True, False, True]
t3   = [0, 4, 5]
```